# Precision of locating iBeacon device

Tags: android, mobile, ibeacon

I want to try to make with iBeacon device position of human hands. Does someone know, what is precision of getting iBeacon devices positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the position of human hands is beyond the ability of Bluetooth LE beacons, which **cannot measure direction and can only estimate distance to an accuracy of 0.5 meters** at a distance of 2-3 meters.

More details are available here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html